# What is a broad summary of the differences and similarities between Bhaktic and Vedantic Hinduism?

Tags: vedanta, atma, brahman, bhakti

Eastern Orthodox theologian, David Bentley Hart mentioned during an interview that he is able to reconcile the Christian Trinity with "certain schools of Bhaktic Hinduism and Vedanta".

This got me wondering about both. What are the defining features of these two Hindu traditions?

Note that this question is coming from someone who knows next to nothing about Hinduism. The most detailed doctrinal point about Hinduism that I am aware of  is that located somewhere in the Hindu traditions there is this idea that God (Brahman) and the Soul (Atman) are one and the same thing/reality.

Comment: @UdayKrishna not a particularly helpful comment

Comment: Vedanta itself is too broad and subcategorized into too many. comparing each and every to Bhaktic would be too broad. You might want to rephrase the question by adding that you're looking for some "specific" difference.

Comment: Restrict your question to specific or else question would be closed as broad

Comment: Bhakti is love or devotion to God. It is an aspect of Vedanta. It is not something that is separate from Vedanta. There are sects of Vedanta that stress Bhakti over other modes as a path to God. As it is your question is unclear.

Comment: Vedanta is not independent of bhakti

Comment: There is no difference between those two because Bhakti and Vedantic Hinduism is pretty much the same thing.